# Using JDBC driver and how to fetch relationship information?

Tags: orientdb

I'm testing JDBC OrientDB driver for one of our projects. It seems to be working fine I just have one question. How can I fetch relationship data, is there equivalent for dot notation? Lets consider standard OrientDB demo data with Person and City classes. How can I fetch Person data and get related city name information

e.g.

```
select * from Person and how to get 'city.name' ?
```

Result of query for city value is: `City#11:0{name:Rome,country:Italy} v1`

Answer (score 2):

It's easy:

```
select city.name from Person
```

Comment: I'm getting following error when using field names instead of '*' in select query. 'select * from Person' is fine, 'select name,email from Person' raises error below.

java.lang.NullPointerException
com.orientechnologies.orient.jdbc.OrientJdbcResultSetMetaData.getTableName(OrientJdbcResultSetMetaData.java:245) com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.initMetaData(CachedRowSetImpl.java:753) com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.populate(CachedRowSetImpl.java:633)
com.sun.rowset.internal.CachedRowSetReader.readData(CachedRowSetReader.java:192) com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.execute(CachedRowSetImpl.java:798)

Comment: What release are you using? Can you try using OrientDB 1.7-rc* and the JDBC driver version 1.7-rc2-SNAPSHOT?